# Blank spaces in a font

Tags: text-object

I don't think I had this problem show up on any other font, but recently I tried to use a font called [Road_Rage.otf](https://www.dafont.com/road-rage.font).

The problem is, when I import the font into Blender (Version 2.79), a lot of characters have blank spaces in them, when everywhere else, they show normally.

This is how it should look like:

[image]

And this is how it looks in Blender:

[image]

I don't know what causes it.

Anyone knows how to fix this ?

Comment: same problem here, so maybe type into a vector software then import as svg?

Comment: Nope, It doesn't help to import it as an SVG. I recommend you to report this as a bug at developer.blender.org

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Booleans in 2D Curves don't support self intersecting curves. Text is just a fancy curve.

Two overlapping shapes of the same curve object, will show the difference boolean.

[image: difference]

As you can see in the above gif, there appear to be errors at the intersections, which cause some problems with the tesselation.

[image: problem]

In an [open tasks](https://developer.blender.org/T43902) Campbell Barton says:

> [...] its not a bug because the code is working as intended.
>   Of course adding support for self intersecting curves could be a
>   useful enhancement.

The font features some problematic self intersection bezier shapes, which cause everything to render incorrectly. Removing this shape form the *T* character
[image: problem areas] result in a correct shape.

You can fix this manually by <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> converting the Text to a curve. And then removing the problematic curves.

[image: make curve]

This can be also easily achieved, by separating various parts in edit mode.

[image: sepraate things]